# Install imagemagick in Google Colaboratory

Tags: imagemagick, google-colaboratory

I am trying to save an animation as a gif,via imagemagick package.
This is what I did

`anim.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=10)`

But I am getting the following warning

```
MovieWriter imagemagick unavailable; trying to use <class 'matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter'> instead.
```

Since imagemagick is not a python package , how do I install it in Google colab?
Or , is there a different package that I can use to save an animation as a gif in google colab?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can install it using `apt`

```
!apt install imagemagick
```